# Url rewrite 404 errors

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I am trying to make pretty urls and my htaccess code works but whenever there is an additional / in the url or a part is missing it's throwing 404 errors while the parameters are optional

```
localhost/1/en/home/ -> works
localhost/1/en/home/random -> 404 error
localhost/1/en -> 404 error

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&language=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

What can I do to tell mod_rewrite that the parameters are optional

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)(/.*)?$ index.php?id=$1&language=$2&page=$3 [L]
```